# Read Dynamic array with JSTL

Tags: java, servlets, jstl, javabeans

I got a form that submits 6 numbers. They got the same name.

```
        <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=valores VALUE="${bean.values}" maxlength=2></TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=valores VALUE="${bean.values}" maxlength=2/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=valores VALUE="${bean.values}" maxlength=2/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=valores VALUE="${bean.values}" maxlength=2/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=valores VALUE="${bean.values}" maxlength=2/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=valores VALUE="${bean.values}" maxlength=2/></TD>
```

The I recieve them in Servlet like this:

```
String[] values= request.getParameterValues("values");  
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            hello.setValues(values[i]);
        }

        request.setAttribute("bean", hello);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Test.jsp").forward(request,response);    
    }
```

They are now in the Bean Class, I used setValues for set them.

The thing I want to do is to recieve the same numbers on the form. I used `${bean.values}` but I got 1 number repeated, not the full input array.

Thank You!

Comment: the one number you obtained repeatedly, is this the last number of the text box on your form?

Comment: All assigned same value `${bean.values}` along with same name. Why?

Comment: @Ashish yes the last number.

Comment: @Braj Because I want to make a dynamic table that sum columns and rows. then I got in one tr values0, values1.. etc

Comment: Is this the flow `jsp -> servlet` in your case? Please confirm.

Comment: @devtreat please correct me, but I understand you want to paint in your JSP the array you have defined in bean.values

Comment: You iterating as much as array length and setting `hello.setValues(values[i]);` so you will get the last overriden value. If you want all values set, don't do `for` loop and just call setter, and type must be `String[]' in bean.

Comment: You have written in the title that you want to read with JSTL, but you are not using it, why?

Comment: Can you not use a forEach in the jstl and iterate over the `hello.Values` property and render your jstl accordingly?

Comment: @Braj Well, I post in JSP to Servlet, there I take the values and set them to bean Class, then I retrieve then again in the JSP.

Comment: @Jorge_B yes, I want to print again the array of the bean class in the jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a mistake while filling the form with values:

```
String[] values= request.getParameterValues("values"); // assuming 6 values
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) // do 6 iterations
{
  hello.setValues(values[i]); // I guess #setValues is expecting an array of values
}
```

So your code is supposed to output the last number of the RequestParameter array "values". But you want to display the whole array of numbers, so your code must look more like this:

```
  String[] values= request.getParameterValues("values"); // Receive the array from the request
  hello.setValues(values); // Add the whole array to the bean
```

According to the answer of Jorge_B you can output the array on the JSP via JSTL **c**ore using the forEach loop:

```
<c:forEach var="value" items="${bean.values}"> 
   <td><input type="text" name="valores" value="${value}" maxlength="2"></td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Its posible to do this in the same JSP? set default values like 1,2,4,5,6 then post them to servlet, setvalues in bean and recieve them again in the same JSP?

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to paint in your JSP the entire values array, try something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="value" items="${bean.values}"> 
   <td><input type="text" name="valores" value="${value}" maxlength="2"></td>
</c:forEach>
```

Would this suit you?